# How can I use pandas.DataFrame.to_csv to write pandas.Timestamp with milliseconds?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format

Assume I have a DataFrame containing column with `pandas.Timestamp` objects like this:

```
pandas.Timestamp('2019-12-10T17:16:49.467000000')
```

How can I specify the `date_format` argument of the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` function to recieve CSV-file with milliseconds, not microseconds?

I tried this way:

```
df.to_csv('!test.csv', sep='\t', index=False, date_format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

but it gives string like this: `10.12.2019 17:16:49.467000`

I need string like this: `10.12.2019 17:16:49.467`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, but you can pre-process the columns before exporting:

```
def dt_to_str(s):
    if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype(s):
        return s.dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3]
    return s

df.apply(dt_to_str).to_csv('!test.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Output:

```
num date
1   10.12.2019 17:16:49.467
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't working. It gives the following: `2019-12-10 17:16:49.467000+00:00`

Comment: @ВладимирИвонин then `.str[:-12]`, of you use a different format adapt the length to remove.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Can you try `pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype` in place of `pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype`? In any case it doesn't look like the dataset that you provided, please update your example.

Comment: with `pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype` it works! Thank you!